# Page Content Scroll Over Banner (CSS)

Tags: css, squarespace

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a 'collapsing header', where the page content scrolls over the banner image. This question has been asked thousands of times, I'm sure, but it's an interesting case because of how the header div is setup and the use of the `<main>` tag (using a squarespace template).

I'm hoping this can be achieved with CSS alone, I've had some luck in messing with z-index and position attributes, however I haven't been able to achieve the desired effect. The closest I've gotten is a fixed banner image where the main page text is able to scroll over the banner-- but the banner remains visible behind the text.

I would appreciate any assistance, or just someone pointing me in the right direction!

I found a great example of what I'm going for here https://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-collapsing-header-effect

The website is https://lendr.us

Thank you!!!

Edit:

Here's a CodePen that I've been referencing: c o d e p e n .io/nickcil/pen/oiahg

Basically, the issue is instead of this:

```
<div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div class="content"><h1>Content</h1></div>
```

I have this:

```
<div class="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<main id="page"><h1>Content</h1></div>
```

And I guess that's really the problem, instead of doing just a div overlap, I'm trying to make the main overlap the header div. I'm pretty new to coding so this is all really hard for me, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: can u add your code please? with a jsfiddle demo or something like this

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! In case anyone else is having this issue, this is effectively how you create a parallax effect using the Bedford template.

It was a positioning and z-index issue, here's the CSS I used:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
.transparent-header.view-list .banner-thumbnail-wrapper, .transparent-
header.collection-type-page .banner-thumbnail-wrapper {
padding: 240px 0 155px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
#promotedGalleryWrapper .color-overlay, .promoted-gallery-wrapper .color-
overlay, .banner-thumbnail-wrapper .color-overlay, .sqs-featured-posts-
gallery .color-overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
z-index: 1;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
#thumbnail {
position: fixed;
top: -110px;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
-webkit-animation: feature-bg-anim .6s ease-in-out;
animation: feature-bg-anim .6s ease-in-out;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
.desc-wrapper {
-webkit-animation: feature-text-anim 1.25s ease-in-out;
animation: feature-text-anim 1.25s ease-in-out;
position: relative;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
#page {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: auto;
margin: auto;
max-width: inherit;
padding: auto;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
background: white;
top: 670px;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
#preFooter {
color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 50;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 670px;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 641px) {
#footer {
background-color: #1f1f1f;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 50;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 670px;
}
}
```

Quick and dirty, but it did the job! Hopefully this helps someone having a similar issue!